# can someone explain =+ operator for me in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw some code that happened in javascript:

```
var date = +new Date(); //same as 'var date =+ new Date();'
```

and it gave me a number: 1441863253753
The previous programmer was using this to store unique ids

when I remove the + :

```
var date = new Date();
```

it gave me: "Thu Sep 10 2015 01:36:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

can someone tell me what's going on?

I've seen +=, but never =+

Comment: take note there is a space there, its `= +new Date()` not `=+`.

Comment: adding `+` infront of `new Date()` returns the timestamp _Number_

Comment: @Rey Libutan   var a =+ ''; a = 0; I dont thik there is difference between = +new Date() and =+ new Date()

Comment: I tried both, and it gave me the same thing.. I looked for this in documentations and googling it, but it's kinda hard looking for something like this.. I knew about unary, but completely forgot about it.. including the term "unary" :-p

Comment: @intekhab, yes there is none but I believe its much clearer when the `+` is closer to the `new Date()` because it has nothing to do with `=`. To avoid the confusion the asker is encountering.

Comment: I was gonna make the title "+new" but I thought it was one of those =+ things.. since they were both allowed in javascript

Comment: @Rey I completely agree with you.

Comment: A JavaScript date can be written as a string:

Thu Sep 10 2015 12:02:54 GMT+0530 (IST)

or as a number:

1441866774938

Dates written as numbers, specifies the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.

Coming to your question it seams that by adding '+' after assignment operator '=' , converting Date to equal number value.

same can be achieve using Number() function, like Number(new Date());

    var date = +new Date(); //same as 'var date =number(new Date());'

Answer (score 1):

`+` is unary plus operator used to covert the string into number.
ex : +'5' // 5
It does same as `Number()` does in javascript

For more detail see this                                                         https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Answer (score 0):

`+` converts a value to a number. example:

```
x = "35"
"35"
y = +x
35
typeof y
"number"
```